# How to trigger all Data errors on WPF MVVM form

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am trying to show 'Required' in red text when the form is loaded and the text is empty what is the best way to display all required field once the form is visible?

I have about 7 more textboxes.

XAML:

```
<TextBox x:Name="SubTotalApples" Text="{Binding SubTotalApplesValue, StringFormat={}{0:0.00##}, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}"/>

<TextBox x:Name="SubTotalOranges" Text="{Binding SubTotalOrangesValue, StringFormat={}{0:0.00##}, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}/>
```

ViewModels properties

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
public bool? SubTotalApplesValue 


[Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
public bool? SubTotalOrangesValue
```

Comment: I guess the easiest way would be to make a label displaying "Required", where the visibility is bound to the value of the bool values. You can use the `IValueConverter` interface to control it based on  null values. I'm not sure, if there are built-in options for this usecase in WPF (as opposed to ASP.NET).

Comment: Are the properties really `bool?` and not string or int?